# Combine multiple files and write to new file without duplicates in Java

Tags: java, filereader

I have 2 files with below contents

```
file1.txt
stack 1
overflow 2
frequency 4

file2.txt
stack 2
overflow 1
terms 5
```

I want to combine multiple files like this and create a new file with below output

```
final.txt
stack 3
overflow 3
terms 5
frequency 4
```

**Note : The files are very large in size**

Can anybody help what is best way to do this?

Comment: Try using a `Map<String,Integer>` to hold the counts.

Comment: i can do that but the files are very large so there will be lot of terms and there count so i may get some memory issues.even there will be more than 2 files to be specific it will be 7 files.Do we have any better option ?

Comment: Could you please provide the steps you have taken so far? Did you take any effort by yourself?

Comment: @ Paul Kertscher I have done using Maps as mentioned by @Patrick Parker but as files are very large i wanted to know is there any other better way to do the same

Comment: Java is able to read large files. As long as you aren't loading the entire file into memory at once, you shouldn't run into memory issues.

Comment: I will not be loading entire file into memory but map which holds term and count may give memory issues when i try to read all the files and store the data in a single map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html). Spark is built on the concept of distributed datasets, which contain arbitrary Java or Python objects. You create a dataset from external data, then apply parallel operations to it.

Comment: I am now aware of the spark jobs.do we need HDFS setup to run these spark Jobs?If it is so i cannot have that currently

Comment: No, you can see my example in my github. I read from excel file and make action. https://github.com/nvtam2105/spark-demo